# How to send JSON Array output from android studio to PHP

Tags: php, android, json, sqlite

The code below gets all the rows in my Android SQLite database and covert it to JSON Array. Now I want to get the JSON Array using PHP to store it to my online database. What should I do? Please help.

This is the code that I use:

```
private JSONArray getResults()
{

    String myPath = this.getDatabasePath("cart.db").toString();// Set path to your database

    String myTable = CartContract.CartEntry.TABLE_NAME;//Set name of your table

    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(searchQuery, null );

    JSONArray resultSet     = new JSONArray();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        for( int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++ )
        {
            if( cursor.getColumnName(i) != null )
            {
                try
                {
                    if( cursor.getString(i) != null )
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i) );
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  cursor.getString(i) );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rowObject.put( cursor.getColumnName(i) ,  "" );
                    }
                }
                catch( Exception e )
                {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage()  );
                }
            }
        }
        resultSet.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("FINAL RESULT", resultSet.toString() );
    return resultSet;
}
```

This is the output:

```
 FINAL RESULT: [{"id":"1","food_id":"52","food_price":"30","food_name":"Pink Lemonade","quantity":"5","amount":"150","special_request":""},{"id":"2","food_id":"51","food_price":"30","food_name":"House Blend Iced Tea","quantity":"3","amount":"90","special_request":""}]
```

and I want to put these values here: (online database)
[attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyGkY.png)

how should I do that?

UPDATE: I already send the result of my JSONArray and stored it in "$data" but my problem now is how to insert the values to my online database. By the way, in my PHP code, here is where I store the JSONArray as a string:

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
```

UPDATE: I already made it! Thanks for noticing and answering my question

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some general guidelines. Sending JSON on HTTP calls can get weird because it can contain characters that are special to HTTP. To get around this, encode the JSON with Base 64 on Android and decode it in PHP.

I assume that you can figure out how to base64 encode with Java.

On PHP, you get back your original JSON.

```
$originalJson = base64_decode($inputFromAndroid);
$object = json_decode($originalJson, true);
// Now you have the data as a PHP array.
```

Comment: I am so sorry but I don't have any idea on how to base64 encode with Java. I'm a beginner yet. Can you suggest me a way on how to send the values of my Android SQLite database to online database via PHP?